# isomorphic application using Reactjs & Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have an application composed of Reactjs & Nodejs. What I do is to serve a CRA Reacts app using Expressjs, and put some logic on Nodejs side.

CRA simply posts requests to its own backend for front end, like `/api/greeting`. I can use the same models on Reactjs and also on Nodejs side. For example, a model object of type `Employee` can be used on both sides in a typesafe manner.
Finally, I build a single Docker image for the whole app and deploy it in a single K8s pod.

What I'd like to ask, can this app be called as **isomorphic** as it is? Or are there any more requirements to meet to be called as **isomorphic**?

Answer (score 0):

CRA is client side only. You would need to use something like NextJS instead for SSR support.

Comment: does it make any sense in terms of being isomorphic?

Comment: Will the API be part of the app, or a separate API? Isomorphic just means that the same javascript is run on both the client and the server. On the server html would be returned

Comment: Sorry. My answer wasn't very good. Isomorphic means the app code runs on both the client and the server (in node) and returns html. In your example it's not happening so it's not isomorphic. Any app using CRA won't be isomorphic because it is client side only